# Como acessar uma lista resultante de uma função em outra?

Tags: python

Eu tenho uma função na qual eu obtive uma lista e pretendo usar essa lista numa outra função:

```
def funcao1():
...
lista1 = [.....]


def funcao2():
#preciso de chamar a lista aqui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retorna a lista na função 1 e chama a função 1 dentro da função 2:

```
def funcao1():
    ...
    lista1 = [.....]
    return lista1

def funcao2():
    #preciso de chamar a lista aqui
    lista = funcao1()

funcao2()
```

Ou declara a lista externamente e passa por parâmetro para as duas funções:

```
def funcao1(lista):
    lista.append('valor da funcao 1')

def funcao2(lista):
    print lista

lista = ['valor1', 'valor2']
funcao1(lista)
funcao2(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Além de passar como parâmetro ou definir externamente, você também pode transformar a lista em uma variável global. Exemplo:

```
def primeiro():
   global lista
   lista = [0, 1, 2, 3]
def segundo():
   return lista
```

Neste caso, assim que você executasse a função primeiro, ela definiria a variável lista como variável global. Podendo ser usada na função segundo, por exemplo. Porém, ainda é preferível passar a lista como parâmetro ou mesmo defini-la externamente. Assim você evita erros e facilita a manutenção do código.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor solução ao meu ver, quando é necessário usar um determinado de uma função em outra é: ou utilizar o `return` ou utilizar a passagem de argumentos para isso:

Exemplo utilizando a passagem de argumentos:

```
 lista = [1, 2, 3]

 def funcao1 (lista):

     if (type(lista) is not list) return False       

     #faz alguma coisa com a lsita
     return

def funcao2 (lista):

     // faz alguma coisa com a lsita
       return



funcao1(lista);

funcao2(lista);
```

Exemplo usando o retorno:

```
def funcao ():
     lista = [1, 2, 3]
     // faz alguma coisa com a lsita
     return lista;


lista = funcao1()

funcao2(lista);
```

Comment: Não percebi  o que faz a parte do " lista = funcao1() ... funcao2(lista)"

Comment: Basicamente , o objetivo da primeira função é dar aquela lista e depois na 2º função tenho de usar essa lista

Comment: O retorno de uma função é um resultado obtido através da chamada daquela função. Quando você faz `lista = funcao1()`, você está atribuindo o valor produzido por `funcao1` a uma variável chamada `lista`. Esse é o jeito mais apropriado para passar valores de uma função para outra. Quando você faz `funcao2(lista)`, você está tornando disponível para `funcao2` o objeto `lista`.

Comment: Mas eu depois para usar a lista na 2º função tenho que fazer o " funcao2(lista)" onde ?